# Visual Studio 2022 web project can't open Chrome for debug if Chrome instance is already open

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor wasm project in Visual Studio 2022 and when I run it with Edge chosen as in the first image below it works fine. However if I choose Chrome, and there's already an instance of Chrome running I get the error in the second screenshot. If Chrome is not already running it works. I can't find anything in the output window that looks relevant. I'd prefer to use Chrome for debugging. Anyone know why I'm getting this or what to check?

[image]

[image]